# Passing multiples Django Forms in context[] to templates

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a custom Django user schema to manage roles or user types:

- StudentProfile
- ProfessorProfile
- ExecutiveProfile

Due to part of my AbstractBaseUser model stay so:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_professor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_executive = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    other fields ...
```

I have the `get_student_profile()`,`get_professor_profile()` and `get_executive_profile()` methods to get the profile user data.

I've override the `save()` method in my custom model `User` to save the profile data when is_student or is_professor or is_executive have been checked at moment to create an user, their data will be saved in ther respective models:

```
class StudentProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    origin_education_school = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    current_education_school = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    extra_occupation = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class ProfessorProfile(models.Model):
    CATHEDRAL_PROFESSOR = 'CATHEDRAL'
    RESEARCH_PROFESSOR = 'RESEARCH'
    INSTITUTIONAL_DIRECTIVE = 'DIRECTIVE'

    OCCUPATION_CHOICES = (
        (CATHEDRAL_PROFESSOR, 'Cathedral Professor'),
        (RESEARCH_PROFESSOR, 'Research Professor'),
        (INSTITUTIONAL_DIRECTIVE, 'Institutional Directive'),
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank = False)

class ExecutiveProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank = False)
    enterprise_name = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank = False)
```

I have the forms to each profiles user

```
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        widgets = {'gender':forms.RadioSelect,}
        fields = ("username", "email", "is_student",           "is_professor", "is_executive",)
        model = get_user_model() #My model User

class StudentProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = StudentProfile
        fields = ('origin_education_school',current_education_school',
            'extra_occupation')

class ProfessorProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProfessorProfile
        fields = ('occupation',)

class ExecutiveProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ExecutiveProfile
        fields = ('occupation', 'enterprise_name', 'culturals_arthistic','ecological')
```

I have this URL to access to profile user

```
url(r"^profile/(?P<slug>[\w\-]+)/$",
        views.AccountProfilesView.as_view(
            model=ProfessorProfile),
            name='profile'
    ),
```

In my `AccountProfilesView` I manage the profiles form and send them to template

```
class AccountProfilesView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    # All users can access this view
    model = get_user_model()
    success_url = reverse_lazy('dashboard')
    template_name = 'accounts/profile_form.html'
    fields = '__all__'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AccountProfilesView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user = self.request.user

        if not self.request.POST:
            if user.is_student:
                profile = user.get_student_profile()
                context['userprofile'] = profile
                context['form_student'] = forms.StudentProfileForm()
            elif user.is_professor:
                profile = user.get_professor_profile()
                context['userprofile'] = profile
                context['form_professor'] = forms.ProfessorProfileForm()
                print ("profesor form is", context['form_professor'])
            elif user.is_executive:
                profile = user.get_executive_profile()
                context['userprofile'] = profile
                context['form_executive'] = forms.ExecutiveProfileForm()
            elif user.is_student and user.is_professor and user.is_executive:
                student_profile = user.get_student_profile()
                professor_profile = user.get_professor_profile()
                executive_profile = user.get_executive_profile()
                context['student_profile'] = student_profile
                context['professor_profile'] = professor_profile
                context['executive_form'] = executive_profile

                student_form = forms.StudentProfileForm()
                professor_form = forms.ProfessorProfileForm()

                executive_form = forms.ExecutiveProfileForm()

                context['form_student'] = student_form
                context['form_professor'] = professor_form
                context['form_executive'] = executive_form
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        context = super(AccountProfilesView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
        user = self.request.user
        if user.is_student:
            context['form_student'] = forms.StudentProfileForm(self.request.POST)
        elif user.is_professor:
            context['form_professor'] = forms.ProfessorProfileForm(self.request.POST)
        elif user.is_executive:
            context['form_executive'] = forms.ExecutiveProfileForm(self.request.POST)

        elif user.is_student and user.is_professor and user.is_executive:
            context['form_student'] = forms.StudentProfileForm(self.request.POST)
            context['form_professor'] = forms.ProfessorProfileForm(self.request.POST)
            context['form_executive'] = forms.ExecutiveProfileForm(self.request.POST)

        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data(form=form)
        user = self.request.user
        user = form.save()
        if user.is_student:
            student = context['form_student'].save(commit=False)
            student.user = user
            student.save()
        elif user.is_professor:
            professor = context['form_professor'].save(commit=False)
            professor.user = user
            professor.save()
        elif user.is_executive:
            executive = context['form_executive'].save(commit=False)
            executive.user = user
            executive.save()

        elif user.is_student and user.is_professor and user.is_executive:
            student = context['form_student'].save(commit=False)
            student.user = user
            student.save()

            professor = context['form_professor'].save(commit=False)
            professor.user = user
            professor.save()

            executive = context['form_executive'].save(commit=False)
            executive.user = user
            executive.save()
        return super(AccountProfilesView, self).form_valid(form)
```

What happen is that in the `get_context_data()` method the `context['form_professor'] = forms.ProfessorProfileForm()` and `context['form_executive'] = forms.ExecutiveProfileForm()` have been not passing to template

When I create the user with student profile (`is_student`) or with professor profile (`is_professor`) or with executive profile (`is_executive`) all works O.K., this mean, to the users profile by separated (users with only one profile) the render form profiles show the form according to the fields to profile respective.

In this sense, in the `get_context_data()` section, the following code works and pass the forms respective:

```
if user.is_student:
    profile = user.get_student_profile()
    context['userprofile'] = profile
    context['form_student'] = forms.StudentProfileForm()
elif user.is_professor:
    profile = user.get_professor_profile()
    context['userprofile'] = profile
    context['form_professor'] = forms.ProfessorProfileForm()
    print ("profesor form is", context['form_professor'])
elif user.is_executive:
    profile = user.get_executive_profile()
    context['userprofile'] = profile
    context['form_executive'] = forms.ExecutiveProfileForm()
```

But when I create an user with three profiles checked (`is_student`, `is_professor`, `is_executive`) just pass the  `context['form_student'] = forms.StudentProfileForm()`

My template in where I show the data is:

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% block title_tag %}Accounts | Profile | iHost {{ block.super }}{% endblock %}
{% block body_content %}
<div class="container">
    <h1>My Profile</h1>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}

        # I ask for user profile of a separate way

        # Student Profile User  
        {% if userprofile.user.is_student %}
        <br/><hr>
            Student form
            {% bootstrap_form form_student %}
        {% endif %}

        # Professor Profile User  
        {% if userprofile.user.is_professor %}
            {{ form_professor.as_p }}
        {% endif %}

        # Executive Profile User       
        {% if userprofile.user.is_executive %}  
            {{ form_executive.as_p }}
           {% comment %} {% bootstrap_form form_executive %}{% endcomment %}
        {% endif %}

        # I ask for an user with three profiles

        {% if userprofile.user.is_student  %}
        <br/><hr>
        Student form
            {% if userprofile.user.is_professor %}
                {% if userprofile.user.is_executive %}
                    {% bootstrap_form form_student %}
                    <br/><hr>
                    Professor form does not arrive
                    {{ form_professor.as_p }}
                    {% comment %}  {% bootstrap_form form_professor %}{% endcomment %}
                    <br/><hr>
                    Executive form does not arrive
                    {{ form_executive.as_p }}    
                    {% comment %}
                    {% bootstrap_form form_student %}
                    {% bootstrap_form form_professor %}
                    {% endcomment %}         
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
<br /><br /><br />

        <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" class="btn btn-default">
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

When I sign In with a user with three profiles, and I render the profile form, I get this behavior in relation to forms rendered.
form_professor and form_executive is not renderized

[image]

By this reason, I think that the professor and executive form instances does not have been passing to template,

This also is verified, because if I remove the comments and use `django-bootstrap3` application in my template I cannot get the `form_professor` and `form_executive` instances form

- `form_professor` does not arrive to template
  [image]
- `form_executive` does not arrive to template
  [image]

In addition, although I think so that I can perform better the conditional logic in my template.

What happened to me here. 
My idea is can render the profiles forms according to the profiles to the user in one template.

I appreciate highly their support.

---

**UPDATE**

---

According to the [@Rohan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/229410/rohan) answer below,  It's true, the  `el ... if` statement were the root of the problem. Now the forms render good.

My `AccountProfilesView` stay of this way:

```
class AccountProfilesView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    # All users can access this view
    model = get_user_model()
    #success_url = reverse_lazy('dashboard')
    template_name = 'accounts/profile_form.html'
    fields = '__all__'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AccountProfilesView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user = self.request.user

        if not self.request.POST:
            if user.is_student:
                profile = user.get_student_profile()
                context['userprofile'] = profile
                context['form_student'] = forms.StudentProfileForm()
            if user.is_professor:
                profile = user.get_professor_profile()
                context['userprofile'] = profile
                context['form_professor'] = forms.ProfessorProfileForm()
                print ("profesor form is", context['form_professor'])
            if user.is_executive:
                profile = user.get_executive_profile()
                context['userprofile'] = profile
                context['form_executive'] = forms.ExecutiveProfileForm()
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        context = super(AccountProfilesView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
        user = self.request.user
        if user.is_student:
            context['form_student'] = forms.StudentProfileForm(
                self.request.POST)
        if user.is_professor:
            context['form_professor'] = forms.ProfessorProfileForm(
                self.request.POST)
        if user.is_executive:
            context['form_executive'] = forms.ExecutiveProfileForm(
                self.request.POST)
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data(form=form)
        user = self.request.user
        user = form.save()
        if user.is_student:
            student = context['form_student'].save(commit=False)
            student.user = user
            student.save()
        if user.is_professor:
            professor = context['form_professor'].save(commit=False)
            professor.user = user
            professor.save()
        if user.is_executive:
            executive = context['form_executive'].save(commit=False)
            executive.user = user
            executive.save()
        return super(AccountProfilesView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('dashboard')
```

But now, when I want save the forms deployed product of the three profiles, I get this error message.

```
File "/home/bgarcial/workspace/ihost_project/accounts/views.py", line 181, in post
    context['form_student'] = forms.StudentProfileForm(self.request.POST)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/ihost/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/http/response.py", line 142, in __setitem__
    value = self._convert_to_charset(value, 'latin-1', mime_encode=True)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/ihost/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/http/response.py", line 115, in _convert_to_charset
    raise BadHeaderError("Header values can't contain newlines (got %r)" % value)
django.http.response.BadHeaderError: Header values can't contain newlines (got '<tr><th><label for="id_origin_education_school">Origin education institute:</label></th><td><input id="id_origin_education_school" maxlength="128" name="origin_education_school" type="text" value="Universidad CES, Escuela de Ingeniería" required /></td></tr>\n<tr><th><label for="id_current_education_school">Current education institute:</label></th><td><input id="id_current_education_school" maxlength="128" name="current_education_school" type="text" value="Universidad CES" required /></td></tr>\n<tr><th><label for="id_extra_occupation">Extra occupation:</label></th><td><input id="id_extra_occupation" maxlength="128" name="extra_occupation" type="text" value="Networker" required /></td></tr>')
[08/Apr/2017 16:45:05] "POST /accounts/profile/milena/ HTTP/1.1" 500 108439
```

There is some inconvenient when form is going to be render and I make sure to fill this forms with data entered in a POST method, that error happen and this screen I get:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its problem with python code in the `get_context_data` function. You should not use `if..elif..` to add required forms. With your code if a user has all profiles, the code will only go into 1st `if` and add only student profile form.

So rather you should have separate `if` statements for all types of profiles. In that case you do not need last `if` with `and`ing for all types.

So change your code to

```
if user.is_student:
    profile = user.get_student_profile()
    context['userprofile'] = profile
    context['form_student'] = forms.StudentProfileForm()

#NOTE: no elif, only if
if user.is_professor:
    profile = user.get_professor_profile()
    context['userprofile'] = profile
    context['form_professor'] = forms.ProfessorProfileForm()
    print ("profesor form is", context['form_professor'])

if user.is_executive:
    profile = user.get_executive_profile()
    context['userprofile'] = profile
    context['form_executive'] = forms.ExecutiveProfileForm()

# NO need for last if user.is_student and user.is_professor and user.is_executive:
```

Comment: It's true, the  `el ... if` statement were the root of the problem. Now the forms render good. My apologies, these were a newbie error.  In this moment my forms are not saved in the database. I think that there is clear for Django what form is going to renderised and saved in the `request.POST` instance. Can check you my **UPDATE** above in my original question please. I appreciate your orientation.

Comment: @bgarcial, I'm not sure about that error. Its good practice to post new question for new problem.

Comment: you have reason. This error I already  solve but create another problem which I post in other question. Ket me share with you this new question just in case that you can support me. http://stackoverflow.com/q/43314269/2773461